# SlowCheetah XML transformation Preview not working with custom transformation

Tags: web-config, xslt, slowcheetah

SlowCheetah is great, but I'm trying to get it to work with [Sayed's custom transformation to support replacing partial text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915329/advanced-tasks-using-web-config-transformation)

When I try to preview a transform I get "There was an error processing the transformation."  I'm just using the [project here](http://sedodream.com/2010/09/09/ExtendingXMLWebconfigConfigTransformation.aspx) as I would like to use both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently preview for custom transforms are not supported for web.config. Sorry. This would actually be very challenging from a technical perspective as well. I have created an issue for this on the project site at https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/issues/6, but it won't be implemented anytime soon.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sayed. I enjoyed your book.