# Replacement of some tags in web.config in a section

Tags: c#, .net, web.config-transform, config-transformation

I want to replace some tags from appsettings section but not all of them, and I don't want to write

```
xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"
```

for all of them, is there any pattern matching available so I can transform all the ones that start with a certain prefix. Example

```
<appsettings>
    <add key="a" value="a" />
    <add key="r_a" value="X" />
    <add key="r_b" value="B" />
</appsettings>
```

and use a transform that replaces the ones starting with _r at the appsettings level?

Haven't found anything yet.

Comment: The poster [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31232684/1016183) had the same problem as you, they solved it with their own version of a custom transform as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3674169/1016183).